# Video drivers not loading on 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

After trying to get hardware acceleration working for ffmpeg, I've messed up my installation. I no longer get a GUI and video drivers aren't showing as in use. Trying to re-install packages I think I'm now only making it worse! I did try X -configure, but assume that's not going to work until there's a driver loaded.

Installation is Ubuntu 22.04, all should be up to date.

```
uname -a
Linux server 6.5.0-18-generic #18~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Feb  7 11:40:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There's an onboard intel GPU (that I did have working to provide ffmpeg hardware acceleration before a recent apt upgrade) and a PCIe AMD card.

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R5 430 OEM / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 87
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ef300000-ef33ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=800,600
```

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false quiet splash"`

If I try `modprobe i915` I currently get `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'i915': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)`

dmesg shows

```
[ 3668.482231] drm_display_helper: Unknown symbol cec_transmit_attempt_done_ts (err -2)
[ 3668.482354] drm_display_helper: Unknown symbol cec_s_phys_addr (err -2)
[ 3668.482399] drm_display_helper: Unknown symbol cec_s_conn_info (err -2)
[ 3668.482426] drm_display_helper: Unknown symbol cec_s_phys_addr_from_edid (err -2)
[ 3668.482780] drm_display_helper: Unknown symbol cec_unregister_adapter (err -2)
[ 3668.482921] drm_display_helper: Unknown symbol cec_allocate_adapter (err -2)
[ 3668.483044] drm_display_helper: Unknown symbol cec_fill_conn_info_from_drm (err -2)
[ 3668.483067] drm_display_helper: Unknown symbol cec_received_msg_ts (err -2)
[ 3668.483165] drm_display_helper: Unknown symbol cec_register_adapter (err -2)
```

I'm not sure what driver the AMD card should be using.

Any suggestions to avoid a complete OS re-install gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've got X up and running again after purging some partly installed packages then:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-all
sudo X -configure
```

I found inxi is quite useful:

```
$ inxi -GISxxy
System:
  Host: server Kernel: 6.5.0-21-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Console: pty pts/0 DM: GDM3 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 vendor: Dell driver: N/A bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:1912
  Device-2: AMD Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R5 430 OEM R7 240/340 Radeon 520 OEM] vendor: Dell driver: N/A pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 8 bus-ID: 01:00.0
    chip-ID: 1002:6611
  Display: server: X.org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: ati,intel,vesa
    unloaded: amdgpu,fbdev,modesetting,radeon gpu: N/A tty: 242x102
  Message: GL data unavailable in console. Try -G --display
Info:
  Processes: 502 Uptime: 1m Memory: 31.2 GiB used: 3.1 GiB (9.9%)
  Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 target: graphical.target Compilers:
  gcc: 11.4.0 alt: 11/12 Packages: 2378 apt: 2363 snap: 15 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 running-in: pty pts/0 inxi: 3.3.13
```

Trying to use modprobe for i915 or radeon still gives
`Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)`

And I still haven't got any hardware acceleration working, but at least I can use a GUI again.